# Update Profile Picture and Name in Navigation Drawer in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, navigation-drawer

First of all I want to say that I implemeted the Navigation Drawer using Activities instead of Fragments. The issue I'm facing is how can I update the profile picture and name of the current user from the firestore?

Here is the layout

[Layout Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkgUW.png)

I created a Fragment and linked it with the layout above mentioned in the picture. But how do I use this fragment on each activity that is opened so that whenever the navigation drawer is shown this code runs and the picture is updated.

```
public class DrawerFragment extends Fragment {
    ImageView profilepic;
    TextView name;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
    ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, container, false);

        profilepic = view.findViewById(R.id.displayPic);
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.namE);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("Users").document(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        documentReference.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String Name = snapshot.getString("fName");
                        String profilePic = snapshot.getString("imageURL");
                        name.setText(Name);
                        Picasso.get().load(profilePic).into(profilepic);
                    }
                });

        return view;
    }
}
```

and here is how I'm navigating between activities

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.drawer_home:
     break;
        case R.id.drawer_onging:
        case R.id.drawer_history:
            startActivity(new Intent(DriverCreatePostActivity.this,DriverHistoryPost.class));
            break;
        case R.id.drawer_profile:

        case R.id.drawer_contact:

        case R.id.drawer_share:

        case R.id.drawer_privacy:

        case R.id.drawer_about:

        case R.id.drawer_logout:
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}enter code here
```

Comment: None of the code you shared accesses Firestore, or any part of Firebase. It'll be hard to help without seeing what you've tried, or at the very least what exact data you're trying to update. If you're looking to update a user profile in Firebase **Authentication**, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

Comment: added the firebase code aswell. The issue isn't what I'm supposed to code what I was asking is that where can I place this so that the navigation drawer layout gets updated no matter on which activity I am on. I hope I explained the problem

Comment: Your initial question explicitly asked about getting data from Firestore. If the Firestore code isn't relevant to the question, don't include it and don't tag with `google-cloud-firestore`.

Comment: because the question is related to firestore! that's why I tagged it here. Sorry for being a starter but I thought I should include everything that's connected to the question

Comment: From your latest update the problem seems purely Android layout related, and my comments may have kept others more knowledgable on that front from helping. I'd highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it explains how and why to isolate the problem.